# Add numpy arrays together to create new array with max absolute value

Tags: python, numpy

I have multiple numpy arrays and I would like to add the numbers together, but ignore numbers that decrease the absolute value of the result. So for the first iteration, I want to add the numbers 10, -20 and 50. But I ignore the -20 value because that reduces the absolute value of the result. But for the next iteration, I want to ignore the 100 value. Is there an easy way to do this?

`array 0: [10, 100]`

`array 1: [-20, -40]`

`array 2: [50, -70]`

`desired result: [60, -110]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how it is related to numpy. But in an algoritmic point of view, you can get it done like this:

```
positives=[]
negatives=[]
result=[]
for i in range(len(array1)):
    if array0[i]<0:
        negatives.append(array0[i])
        positives.append(0)
    else:
        positives.append(array0[i])
        negatives.append(0)

    if array1[i]<0:
        negatives[i]+=array1[i]
    else:
        positives[i]+=array1[i]

    if array2[i]<0:
        negatives[i]+=array2[i]
    else:
        positives[i]+=array2[i]


for i in range(len(array1)):
    if positives[i] >= -  negatives[i]:
        result.append(positives[i])
    else:
        result.append(negatives[i])

return result
```